# why JMeter is not scanning for JAR file from JMETER_HOME/lib/junit folder

Tags: jmeter, junit4

I have successfully exported JAR file from Eclipse to **JMETER_HOME/lib/junit** but when I try to import it in JUnit sampler of JMeter. It doesn't shows in

Answer (score 0):

It does, however there are few things you need to remember:

1. You need to restart JMeter to pick the jar with your JUnit tests up
2. If your .jar file has dependency jars you need to put them somewhere into [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) as well. Again, JMeter restart will be required so JMeter could read the .jar(s)
3. In the [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) Sampler itself you need to tick `Search for JUnit 4 annotations (instead of JUnit 3)` box

   [image: JUnit 4 Annotations]
4. Check *jmeter.log* file in case of any unexpected behaviour, it usually contains enough information to troubleshoot the issue.

Detailed information on JUnit and JMeter integration is available in the [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) article.